# Current transformer using LTspice

Tags: ltspice, current-transformer

I am trying to simulate the secondary current of a current transformer with the following parameters:

- CT ratio 1:200
- primary current 15A
- Lprimary 2.225nH
- Lsec 89mH

With the proportionality of inductance : L1/L2=(N1/N2)^2. So in my case that equals to 25*10^-6.

The secondary current after the simulation is 1.531mA. Is the result correct? Shouldn't it be 15A/200 = 75mA?

[image]

Comment: Please ask a question and note that *4 loops throuht de primary -Lprimary 2.225nH* is unfeasible

Comment: Do you need a verification of the simulator software?

Comment: @Jens yes please.

Comment: What if you change `2.225n` to `2.225u` ?

Comment: @SteKulov i can t because i need to respect the inductance proportionality : L1/L2=(N1/N2)^2

Comment: Your math is completely wrong.  You calculated the inductance of the primary when the secondary is 1H.  Write it out on paper.  Pick 89mH for secondary and solve for the primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My calculations for the values shown by LTspice indicate a turns ratio of 6289/1. So with 10.6 A RMS the current through R1 is shown to be 1.538 mA whereas my calculated value is 1.685 mA **RMS**.

If the CT has primary inductance of 2.225 **uH**, then the ratio is 198/1 and the output would be 53.3 mA RMS or 76 mA **peak**.